# How do I generate a PDF report using data from forms in php?

Tags: html, forms, pdf

I tried using `mpdf` but it didn't work out well for me, is there any other easy to use libraries for PHP?

Edit : `TCPDF` worked out well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not mentioned server side programming language, if using PHP then you can use TCPDF which will convert your HTML to PDF. Can go through [this document](https://tcpdf.org/docs/) for more information.

Comment: Yes, I'm using PHP for the back-end. Thanks, I'll check that out.

Comment: Please upvote if that helps